# Method overloading and polymorphism Revisited

Tags: c#, oop, interface, polymorphism, overloading

Something like this should be possible in C#, right?

```
    public void Start ()
    {
        Class1 x = new Class1 ();

        string s = Something (x);

        Console.ReadKey ();
    }

    public string Something (IInterface obj)
    {
        return foo (obj);  //  <-- Problem line
    }

    public string foo (Class1 bar)
    {
        return "Class1";
    }

    public string foo (Class2 bar)
    {
        return "Class2";
    }

    interface IInterface {}

    class Class1 : IInterface {}

    class Class2 : IInterface {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Your `foo` methods expect either `Class1` or `Class2`.  You're passing an `IInterface` which could be either `Class1` or `Class2`.  It won't compile because the compiler doesn't know which overloaded method to call.  You would have to cast it to one of the types to get it to compile.

Alternatively, `IInterface` would hold the `foo` method that took no arguments and returned which class it was.  Then something could take the `IInterface` object and call `obj.foo()`

Like:

```
interface IInterface 
{ 
    public string foo(); 
}

class Class1 : IInterface
{
     public string foo()
     {
         return "Class1";
     }
}

class Class2 : IInterface
{
     public string foo()
     {
         return "Class2";
     }
}

public void Something(IInterface obj)
{
    return obj.foo();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be return obj.foo(); instead of return foo(obj);

Comment: This worked. I was just playing around with trying to removing conditional logic on a service call, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Something (IInterface obj)
{
    return foo ((Class1)obj); 
    OR // There's no way compiler to know with method to call.
    return foo ((Class2)obj); 
}

public string foo (Class1 bar)
{
    return "Class1";
}

public string foo (Class2 bar)
{
    return "Class2";
}
```

Comment: This just fixes the compile but doesn't accomplish the goal.

Comment: @Erik. Whats your goal? You don't mention.

Comment: I have no goal but the original poster seems confused on why the code posted will not work. I thought this answer was not particularly helpful as it is. It doesn't explain why the original poster's code won't work, how it could be re-factored to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, where non-virtual calls go is determined at compile time, so you can't call different methods depending on the type at runtime.

What you might be looking for is virtual methods:

```
public void Start () {
  Class1 x = new Class1();

  string s = Something(x);

  Console.ReadKey();
}

public string Something (BaseClass obj) {
  return obj.foo();
}

abstract class BaseClass {
  abstract string Foo();
}

class Class1 : BaseClass {

  public override string foo () {
    return "Class1";
  }

}

class Class2 : BaseClass {

  public override string foo () {
    return "Class2";
  }

}
```